# Soy chicken on a backpacking trip

Tags: food-safety, chicken, soy, camping

I'm planning a long distance hike and I would like to add some variety to my meal planning.  Does soy chicken need refrigeration?  Does it keep for a couple days?

Comment: See:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat

Comment: Why don't you buy the preservative-laden canned ones, from the local Asian store?

Answer (score 2):

Protein of any sort tends to spoil somewhat quickly when it contains water. I suggest you bring icepacks and eat any meat or meat substitutes on your first night if you want to bring them at all. For the rest of the trip, perhaps you could get your protein from dry beans you soak at the camp, meat jerky, nuts and seeds in sufficient quantity, or fish you catch on the trip yourself (while observing all local laws and regulations on the subject).